# Powershell: WMI Ping piped to variable

Tags: loops, powershell, wmi, ping

I'm having some difficulties in getting my PowerShell script to work as I'd like it to and after much jiggery-pokery here I am.

My overall aim is fairly simple, unfortunately I'm somewhat of a PowerShell noob!
I'm trying to determine the name, manufacturer and model of all of the systems in our estate without having to walk around staring at lots of tin.

I've constructed the following based solely on my bad knowledge of scripting and I've hit a snag.

My idea was to pass DNS/IP information from a CSV into a variable which I can then use in turn to perform the WMI query based on the Ping results.
False Ping response = do not query
True Ping response = perform WMI query

Here is what I've got so far...

```
Test-connection -computername
foreach ($Ping in $Hosts) 
{
     test-connection -computername $Ping.IP -count 1 -quiet
     if ($Ping.StatusCode -eq 0)
     {Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -computername $ip.Name | select Name,Manufacturer,Model } out-file c:\CSV\Test1.csv -ea SilentlyContinue}
     else
     {write-host $Hosts.Status Offline}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have file C:\CSV\Hosts.csv with contents as described:

```
computer1.mydomain.com
computer2.mydomain.com
```

With the following script you'll get file C:\CSV\Results.csv:

```
$Hosts = Get-Content "C:\CSV\Hosts.csv"

foreach ($PingIP in $Hosts) 
{

     $alive = Test-Connection -ComputerName "$PingIP" -count 1 -quiet
     if ($alive)
     {
        Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName "$PingIP" | Select Name, Manufacturer, Model | Out-File "C:\CSV\Results.csv" -ea SilentlyContinue
     }
     else
     {
        Write-Output "$PingIP offline"
     }
}
```

Comment: Recently found this code: `$results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\CSV\Results.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation`